# Angular call a service on run

Tags: angularjs

I have a service for handle the menu of my application I dont want call from any controller, where is the best place for call my service

my service has a `register` method

```
// sample

menuService.register({name: "Person", label: "Person", url: "/persons"});
menuService.register({name: "Company", label: "Companies", url: "/companies"});
```

is defined like

```
app.service('MenuService', ['$rootScope', function($r) { /*...*/ }
```

Note: my service `$rootScope.$emit` and is listen by a directive and depends of `$rootScope` and `$location`

Comment: That directive you mentioned is for showing the menu options?

Comment: yeah! but after a while i think maybe is a mistake use $emit and $on when is possible thant the $on listener can't be attach when the $emit is called

Answer (score 1):

you should use `.run` block for that, but keep in mind you cannot inject `.provider` to run block

```
  yourApp.run(function ($rootScope, $location) {
                // your code goes herer
        });
```

[from docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module)

Run blocks are the closest thing in Angular to the main method. A run block is the code which needs to run to kickstart the application. It is executed after all of the services have been configured and the injector has been created. Run blocks typically contain code which is hard to unit-test, and for this reason should be declared in isolated modules, so that they can be ignored in the unit-tests.

Comment: the problem is when i call the service from `.run` method the directive is not ready and dont work

Comment: if you depend on your directive thats mean you can call it from your directive

Answer (score 0):

You could expose the menus as a model in the `MenuService`.

```
app.service('MenuService', ['$rootScope', function($r) { 
  var svcModel = {
    menus: []
  };

  var registerMenu = function(menu) {
    svcModel.menus.push(menu);
  };

  /*...*/

  return {
    model: svcModel,
    register: registerMenu
    /*...*/
  };
}
```

And then access that model directly on the directive:

```
app.directive('menuDirective', ['MenuService', function(MenuService) {
  return {
    /*...*/
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      /*...*/
      scope.menus = MenuService.model.menus;
    }
}]);
```